# loop - calling a series of indexed data

Tags: python, for-loop, std, stderr

I'm trying to generate a list of `std_error` by calling all the `std_dev`_of_sample_means by its `[i]` index and dividing that by its respective `[i^.5]`, but I'm not sure how to properly call the `[i]` in the `std_dev_of_sample_means`. thanks!

```
sample_sizes2 = np.arange(1,1001,100)

mean_of_sample_means = []
std_dev_of_sample_means = []
for i in sample_sizes2:
    probabilities=make_throws(200,i)
    mean_of_sample_means.append(np.mean(probabilities))
    std_dev_of_sample_means.append(np.std(probabilities))
    std_error = std_dev_of_sample_means[i]/(i^.5)

print(std_dev_of_sample_means)
print(std_error)
```

Comment: may i know what do you mean by " I'm not sure how to properly call the [i] in the std_dev_of_sample_means"? What are the errors when you run this code?

Comment: from what i can see here `std_error = std_dev_of_sample_means[i]/(i^.5)` will throw out a `IndexError: list index out of range` because you are iterating through each element in `sample_sizes2` which is `[1,101,201,...]`

Comment: @chowsai sorry for being unclear, but I'd like to get a list of std dev errors for each of the sample sizes. So in other words, for a sample size of 100, I'd have the mean, standard dev, and standard error ...

Comment: so `std_error` would be like a list of standard errors just like `mean_of_sample_means` and `std_dev_of_sample_means`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for :) Do let me know if i misinterpreted your question

```
sample_sizes2 = np.arange(1,1001,100)

mean_of_sample_means = []
std_dev_of_sample_means = []
std_errors = []
for i in sample_sizes2:
    probabilities=make_throws(200,i)
    mean_of_sample_means.append(np.mean(probabilities))
    std_dev_of_sample_means.append(np.std(probabilities))
    std_errors.append(std_dev_of_sample_means[-1]/(i**.5)) # previously it was i^.5

print(std_dev_of_sample_means)
print(std_errors)
```

`std_dev_of_sample_means[-1]` refers to the value of the last element in the list (because the `[-1]` access the last value in the list). In this case it is the value that you just appended to `std_dev_of_sample_means`

Edit 1: changed `i^.5` to `i**.5`. You were using ^ when you want a ** to raise a value to a power. Python interprets this as an xor.

Comment: thanks @chowsai - it's close i think... I get your logic.. but seems like the system doesn't like it yet... "TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: hmm which line is that referring to?

Comment: changed `i^.5` to `i**.5`

Comment: my pleasure :) .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want to use `enumerate()` to get the index and value of the `for-loop`

```
sample_sizes2 = np.arange(1,1001,100)

mean_of_sample_means = []
std_dev_of_sample_means = []
for index,value in enumerate(sample_sizes2):
    probabilities=make_throws(200,value)
    mean_of_sample_means.append(np.mean(probabilities))
    std_dev_of_sample_means.append(np.std(probabilities))
    std_error.append(std_dev_of_sample_means[index]/(value**.5))  *-edit: added append and changed ^ to **

print(std_dev_of_sample_means)
print(std_error)
```